# Is $-2$ a quadratic residue or quadratic non-residue mod $307$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is $-2$ a quadratic residue (QR) or quadratic non-residue mod $307$?

Here is how I tried to solve it:
by the definition of a QR: there exists a $x$ such that

$x^2 \equiv a$ mod $307$

so,
$x^2 \equiv -2$ mod $307$
 or $x^2 \equiv305$ mod $307$

And here is where I got stuck.

Comment: Do you know quadratic reciprocity or not?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $304$ is divisible by $8$, so $307\equiv 3\pmod{8}$.

Because $307\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, the number $-1$ is a NR of $307$.

Also, because $307\equiv 3\pmod{8}$, the number $2$ is a NR of $307$ (standard fact).

Thus $(-1)(2)$ is a QR of $307$ (the product of two NR is a QR).

Comment: $108^2 = 305 \mod 307$